# Grouping MySQL entries only if a field is not NULL, else another field with CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

I have a `books` table that stores books editions. Often, the same book is inserted several times in my database because it exists in different forms (hardcover, paperback, ebook, etc.). Each book have the following fields (among others) :

- id (which is a unique primary key)
- title
- item (which is a int, two different forms of the same book will have the same item, book that
  exists in only one form will be NULL)

Now if have another `sales` table that stores sales and looks like that :

- id (unique primary key)
- book_id (which relates to book.id)
- date (the date when the sale happened)

I need to get a list of best-sellers book, grouping the differents editions of the books as if there were the same book, so my sql query looks like :

```
    SELECT `books`.`title`, COUNT(`sales`.`id`) 
    FROM `sales` 
    JOIN `books` ON `books`.`id` = `sales`.`book_id` 
    GROUP BY (CASE WHEN `item` IS NOT NULL THEN `item` ELSE `books`.`id` END)
```

The problem is that the book « Margherita Dolcevita » that has id 27057 and item NULL gets grouped with the book « Master of the storm » that has id 49522 and item 27057.

What do I need to change in my sql query (preferably) or in my database scheme to get what I want with only one query ?

Comment: why not to group by a book title?

Comment: Because a few books have the same title but have nothing in common, sadly.

Comment: I would try grouping by 2 fields, both item and books.id - _GROUP BY item, IF(item IS NULL, books.id, NULL)_ . This should group them all by item, and for those with a NULL item it will also group by id

Comment: Group by Book.id * 10000 + case when item is null then -1 else item end

Comment: The solution proposed by @Kickstart should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the `CASE` from the `GROUP BY` clause. You mix there "item" with "id".

Ideally, you should keep a single entry for any book in the `books` table and have a different table for the book formats having these fields:

- id (PK, autoincrement);
- book_id (FK, `books`.`id`);
- format (integer, string, whatever fits your design);

Using your current design, try to make the ranges of the two IDs you use in the `CASE` expression to not overlap (f.e. add a prefix to `books`.`id`):

```
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN `item` IS NOT NULL THEN `item` ELSE CONCAT('book-', `books`.`id`) END)
```

A simpler form (and easier to read and understand) of the same expression is:

```
GROUP BY IFNULL(`item`, CONCAT('book-', `books`.`id`))
```

Comment: Indeed the better solution would be to create a third table, sadly I can't do that becase item codes are in fact sometimes imported from another public database. Anyway, thanks for your explanation, your solution works fine, although I think I'm gonna go for @Kickstart's for readability.

Comment: If the types of `item` and `books`.`id` are `INT` I think the solution proposed by @Kickstart is faster. Go for it!